# Display JavaScript as editable code in a file

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, file-get-contents

I am working to make html files of a website editable using CKEditor. I want the user should be able to edit the code of any html file via the admin panel. For this purpose I am using the file_get_contents function which seems to work fine except the JavaScript code is not displayed as editable code in the editor. I have tried the fread function as well and it also displays all the contents of the file in editor but I am still unable to get the JavaScript code in the editor as editable code. Any help?

Here's the code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['path']);
if(!$contents) die("Page not found");      
    $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('content') ;
    $oFCKeditor->BasePath = 'fckeditor/' ;
    $oFCKeditor->Width = '100%' ;
    $oFCKeditor->Height = '350' ; 
    if($mode == 'edit')$oFCKeditor->Value = stripslashes($contents);
    $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to display the js? Post your code.
We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: Why don't you edit the JS in a textarea only? Making WYSIWYG editors edit code can be troublesome.

Comment: I am getting all the code except the Javascript code in the editor. I am able to edit the code and save as well.Actually I have to display all the code of the file in editor so that user can edit it as per requirement. It includes all scripts in the page as well.

Comment: I'm using this for my JS/CSS editing in my CMS:
http://codemirror.net/

Comment: What's the contents of the actual js file?

Comment: As I told earlier, user can edit contents of any html page, so telling exactly what is in the JS file is a little hard since every page has its own scripts.

Comment: There is no conflict actually, the code is not displayed in editor. I just want the javascript be displayed as string or normal text in editor so that user can edit the javscript code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor (formerly FCKeditor) is a WYSIWYG(What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get) editor. WYSIWYG Editors take all the html,css & javascript, execute/parse it & try to display the output. so that's the reson Javascript code is not being shown in editor, as the editor is build to parse the javascript & display its output; instead of actual code.

Now, If you want to work directly with code, than its output. there are two options:

1. Use the "**View Source"** button & you should be able to see all the javascript along with other code.There won't be any syntax highlighting but I this would work fine for small edits
2. Use Source code editor: If you want proper syntax highlighting, you have to switch to a source code editor instead of WYSIWYG(What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get) editor. example of some source code editor

   - http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ its the same editor that you see here on stackoverflow

Comment: @Gaurisha you have got my point the information is really helpful but the problem is I don't get the script in source as well. The script is like {literal}
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
  jQuery("#login").validationEngine();
 });
</script>
{/literal} but in editor i get only {literal} {/literal}